# How to define custom application property in Quarkus Extension with non-fixed key

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-extension

I'm writing a Quarkus Extension (on Quarkus 2.16) whose purpose is to set some fields of a *MyClient* object based on values ​​inserted in the application.properties.

I would like this extension to be able to manage N instances of *MyClient* by reading properties whose key must follow a syntax like:

quarkus.myextension.myclient.*CLIENTNAME-1*.name=Bob

quarkus.myextension.myclient.*CLIENTNAME-2*.name=John

...

quarkus.myextension.myclient.*CLIENTNAME-N*.name=Paul

Where *CLIENTNAME* is a value chosen at will by the user of the extension.

Is there any way to achieve this result? I've seen similar behavior in many extensions (e.g. RestClient) but haven't figured out how to reproduce it

Thanks a lot.

Comment: So you are looking for a config object that will give you this behavior?

Comment: https://smallrye.io/smallrye-config/Main/config/map-support/ for properties mapping and https://quarkus.io/guides/writing-extensions#configuration tell you more about how to use config in extensions

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I had already read WriteYourOwnExtension, but what is not clear to me is how to use the class annotated with @ConfigMap: I see that a Processor class is defined but I don't understand whether it should be inserted in Runtime or Deployment, nor how this class should be used so that I can recover the properties